# universal preprocessor define for C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

my code can be compiled with C or C++ compilers.
I'd like to know which one is doing the compilation

is there preprocessor define to tell me this ?

Comment: look at predefined  `__cplusplus`

Comment: [__cplusplus](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard-Predefined-Macros)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition is `__cplusplus`.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
// treated as C++ code
#else
// treated as C code
#endif // __cplusplus
```